# Least squares with nonlinear constraint

Tags: optimization, least-squares

Here is the problem I faced, 
I was solving this problem at first.
$$Ax=b$$ where $A$ is in shape$(60000,35000)$, but it is a quite sparse matrix, $x$ in shape $(35000, 3)$.

But now I would like to add more constraints. Now I am given another matrix $x_0$ in shape $(500,3)$ which every row in $x_0$ corresponds to some row in $x$. The constraint is that the **angle** of the corresponding rows between $x$ and $x_0$ should be as small as possible.

So I formulate the problem in this way. 
$$\min ||Ax-b||^2+\lambda \sum_iangle(x_{0i},x_{corres(i)})^2$$
where I define $$angle(a,b)=\frac{a\cdot b}{||a||||b||}$$
and $corres(i)$ means the corresponding row in $x$.

How can I solve this problem? I think other form of constraint is also acceptable as long as the constraint makes the angles between the corresponding rows small.

Comment: Well, "as small as possible" could mean 0, as in, just set those 500 rows of $x$ equal to $x_0$ and remove them from the problem (since they are already set.)  Then solve for the remaining (34500, 3) elements of $x$, treating it as an unconstrained problem (which it is, at this point.)